# How can I put some text with transparency and rotation in textbox with xlsxwriter

Tags: graphics, textbox, python-3.4, xlsxwriter

I am using module **xlsxwriter** to generate the sample reports and I want to add a graphic text to sign it. Like this: 
[image]

[image]

I have read the documentation on Xlsxwriter's Site but I cannot find any solutions for setting transparency (I mean that you can see the **Qty** underneath character **l**) and rotation for the text. Could anyone have any ideas on this case?

Answer (score 2):

You can set transparency in a textbox in XlsxWriter by turning the solid fill  and the border off. Here is an example:
    import xlsxwriter

```
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('textbox.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

# Set the column wider for clarity.
worksheet.set_column('A:A', 60)

# Add some sample text.
for row in range(10):
    worksheet.write(row, 0, "Here is some text in the background")

# Set the textbox options.
options = {
    'width': 500,
    'height': 100,
    'font': {'italic': True,
             'color': '#DDDDDD',
             'size': 60},
    'fill': {'none': True},
    'line': {'none': True},
}

# Insert the textbox over the cell text.
worksheet.insert_textbox('A3', 'Sample Report', options)

workbook.close()
```

Output:

[image]

See the [Working with Textboxes](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_textboxes.html) section of the XlsxWriter documentation.

However, I don't think it is possible in Excel to rotate the text in a textbox (apart from vertical and rotate up/down). The option to rotate at an angle is greyed out in Excel.

I think the image in your post is probably achieved using WordArt, which isn't supported by XlsxWriter.

Comment: I tried 'fill' property but It cannot. I mean that I want the text can be transparent. Your suggestion is used to make the background transparent only. Thanks

Comment: AFAIK, it isn't possible to set transparency of a font in a textbox. At least I can't see an option for it Excel.

Comment: I saw your updated comment. But I just want I can see "Here is some text in the background" below the Sample Report. Like this: http://imgur.com/pI54PIr

Comment: I missed you text transparency requirement at first. But as I said I don't think that is possible in textboxes in Excel. If it is let me know and I'll add it to XlsxWriter.

Comment: Thank you. Perhaps, I have to add the word art by manual or without rotation and text transparency. Thanks again.